# excel alert for cell that auto changes

Tags: excel, alert

Hi could someone help adjust this so the alert message says the value of A2 AND B2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F2")
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In myRange
        Evaluate (cell)
        If StrComp(cell, "Yes", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            MsgBox Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A1:A10").Value), Chr$(10))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry i cant find out how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my original post to comply with your better explanation.

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim Cell As Range

    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F2")
    For Each Cell In myRange
        Evaluate (Cell)
        If StrComp(Cell, "Yes", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "A2 = " & CStr((Cells(2, "A").Value) & vbCr & _
                   "B2 = " & CStr(Cells(2, "B").Value))
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for help,  i want the alert message to state the words which are in a2 and b2

Comment: I have modified my original answer to comply with your better explanation.